# In Grails, how can I append a build number when using 'set-version'

Tags: grails, jenkins

I am using Jenkins (Hudson) with the Grails plugin to do builds as I update svn.  I found this example script that allows you to incorporate a build number from an env var:

```
set-version 1.1.0.${env['BUILD_NUMBER']}
```

But as you see, the prefix is hard-coded.  I'd like to use the version number set in the application.properties file.  How can I do something like:

```
set-version ${app.version}.${env['BUILD_NUMBER']}
```

Have tried a variety of scopes/syntax to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible out of the box. Jenkins or specifically the Grails plugin does not read the content of the `application.properties` file and hence the existing application version is not available as a variable.

You might want to consider writing a custom script in your application (like `append-version`) that will read `application.properties` and append the value passed in. You can call the existing [set-version](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/scripts/SetVersion.groovy) script modifying the argument.

I have also created a simple script that should do the job:

```
includeTargets << grailsScript("Init")

target(main: "Append a string to the existing version number") {
    depends(checkVersion, parseArguments)

    def newVersion = metadata.'app.version' + '-' + args
    metadata.'app.version' = newVersion
    metadata.persist()
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am attempting your suggestion, but I'm stuck at invoking the 'set-version' script using mine.  I suspect I need to include the SetVersion groovy file via includeTargets and grailsScript, but after viewing the SetVersion script I don't know what to invoke after the include.

Comment: Yes. Working with grails scripts dependencies is a slight challenge. I'll try to get back with an example.

Comment: This did do the trick, with one catch it took me a while to figure out. The build number kept getting appended additively every time (e.g 3.0.1, 3.0.1.2, 3.0.1.2.3), so be sure to do an 'svn revert' or equivalent as part of the build since the application.properties file is getting changed.